# What are $holors$ and why are they a generalization of tensors concept?

Tags: definition, tensors

I take a look about [Theory of Holors: A Generalization of Tensors](https://books.google.it/books?id=sd9gAg-2kdAC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=Theory%20of%20Holors&source=bl&ots=uhDE9w7X2k&sig=6tOZvxApR4bU_DkacqZ8nHzHyCE&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib2IuqtZfbAhUEDsAKHTFGDL4Q6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=Theory%20of%20Holors&f=false) but I never heard this term "holor"
I thought that the generalization of the tensors were the *supertensors* or hypertensor like that

> A vector or tensor whose components are themselves tensors

is very hard to find a good generalization for tensor. Any idea ?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2565766/104041).

Comment: Tensors need to be generalized?

Comment: I wish to see if is possilble

Comment: If the components of a tensor are tensors, then you still have a tensor. It is not an element in a tensor product of tensor products. Nothing new occurs like that.

Comment: These are tensors with holes.